# Can foreign countries disqualify Australian candidates at will?

Tags: election, constitution, australia

Could a country get their preferred candidates to win an Australian election by declaring all other candidates for that office citizens of that country, thereby making all those other candidates ineligible for the office? Can they get a current office-holder to be dismissed from the post by declaring them a citizen?

Comment: It matters only what citizenships Australia thinks a candidate possesses, not what another country thinks, and it seems the issue, if it ever became a problem, could be simply resolved by not recognizing any "citizenship" which is (1) denied by the alleged citizen and (2) for which the other country has no evidence that the alleged citizen ever requested or accepted.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: But right now, the rules aren’t like that. In most if not all of the recent cases, the politicians involved were unaware that they had the other citizenship, and they had never requested or accepted the citizenship (which they got by birth).

Comment: @Accumulation: For the benefit of everyone who isn’t into Australian politics, perhaps you could add a paragraph about the background (that the Australian constitution forbids dual nationals from sitting in parliament, and that recently a number of cases surfaced where an elected politician had another nationality without being aware of it).

Comment: @bytebuster: have a look at this question; I'm a native-English speaker but at a first glance over this question I find it hard to understand.

Comment: That would be very sneaky and underhanded. On-topic, +1!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Law.SE as it asks how the citizenship laws work.

Comment: @user4012 I'd characterize this question more as about constitutional requirements for being a member of parliament, rather than about citizenship laws - an answer may well be "They'd be ruled as being a dual citizen, but be still allowed to be an MP". I think this would be on topic on law, but a question about laws specifically about politicians may also be on-topic for a site about politics.

Comment: "Even in countries that allow dual citizenship, such as Australia, Jamaica and Pakistan, electoral laws demand that politicians not be under an obligation of allegiance to any foreign country, and so when politicians have been found to be violating such laws, they stepped down and renounced their other citizenships in response to the public controversy" per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renunciation_of_citizenship

Comment: New Zealand: disqualify *all* the politicians! http://www.nzherald.co.nz/world/news/article.cfm?c_id=2&objectid=11906614

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of stating the obvious: This would be considered an act of aggression against Australia *as a nation*, not merely against one political party.

Let's suppose the UK is having trouble negotiating a post-Brexit trade agreement with Australia. It suddenly grants UK citizenship to the Australian Prime Minister and Cabinet. This means they are dismissed from office and the UK can now negotiate with a different Prime Minister, right?

In any practical sense, no. This would be considered unacceptable interference in Australia's internal politics. Most likely, whatever Australian government remained in office would push through emergency legislation to nullify this British mischief-making. The principal effect would be to permanently damage relations between Australia and the UK.

(The UK is just an example, much the same would apply to any other country.)

Comment: The members of parliament probably wouldn't even need to be excluded from voting, someone would have to prove in court that another country can decide _ex parte_ to make a foreign person a citizen, and that such a decision would have legal standing.  Even in the absence of a law specifically preventing it, it seems like a hard sell.

Comment: "Most likely, whatever Australian government remained in office would push through emergency legislation to nullify this British mischief-making." When it's constitutional, what kind of emergency legislation could the government pass?

Answer (score 4):

From an opinion piece published by the public broadcaster Australian Broadcasting Corporation [What the High Court citizenship decision says about the health of our democracy](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-10-27/high-court-citizenship-ruling-health-check-for-our-democracy/9094214)

> The standard is a strict one: It is no excuse, for the purposes of
>   section 44, that an MP has no real ties to a foreign power, or did not
>   in fact know they were a citizen of another country.
>
> But it is not a wholly absolute one: the court recognises foreign
>   countries cannot make it impossible, or unreasonably onerous, to
>   renounce allegiance to that country. To allow this, the court held,
>   would impermissibly undermine "the constitutional imperative that
>   an[y] Australian citizen" be able to participate in representative
>   government.

If a foreign government was trying to deny an Australian citizen being able to be a MP, let alone try to get a particular candidate elected, that would likely not be in contravention of section 44 of the constitution.

Comment: I wonder if the $25K Sam Dastyari's spent on legal fees to renounce his Iranian citizenship would now not be needed. Problem is, that you can't show how onerous it would be without trying.

Comment: On the theme of a legalistic answer there is a fairly detailed answer here: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/22091/4410